# It is possible to setX() to a view which is being animated in his X property?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-view, objectanimator

Having a view which is being animated in his X property:

```
laserXMovement = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "x", startX, endX);
laserXMovement.setDuration(ANIMATION_TIME);
laserXMovement.start();
```

It is possible to do a setX() when the animation is working?

```
view.setX(x);
```

I tested it and it not works. The setX() function has no effect.

Comment: If the view is being animated you'd have to stop the animation or your value would be overwritten and likely never make it to the onDraw call before it's changed by the animation. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini what do you mean with "likely never make it to the onDraw call before it's changed by the animation" ? sorry low english skills

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us a little bit better what you're trying to accomplish. I have the feeling it has not really anything to do with what you're asking. But think that the ObjectAnimator is repeatedly calling "setX" on your view for the ANIMATION_TIME with values from startX to endX. Each of these calls happen "as fast as possible" given the framerate and time interpolator (default in this case). So you calling setX in the middle of an animation will do nothing, for the view has to invalidate itself and call onDraw again (to draw the new position). It's more complicated than that.

Comment: By the time you invalidate the view with your custom "X" value, the animator will have likely changed the value (and invalidated) the view as well, so it all gets piled in the message queue for the UI Thread to actually render/draw the view on screen.

Comment: thank you so much for your aclaration. Now i know that if i want to combine a joystick movement with a animation movement, i must do it on the onDraw.